# Open browser from FCM Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, android-push-notification

I'm trying to open up a browser page to a specific url after the user opens an FCM Push Notification they've received. This is the code I currently have:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class FMMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

On tapping the push notification from the FCM console, nothing happens. I've messed around with this for a while, looking for solutions online, but nothing seems to work.

Please can someone help with this issue?

Take note, I am incredibly new to this and don't understand a whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Data notification with the `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`

```java
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(link));

PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
myNotification.setContentIntent(pending);
```

If the message has data, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the `extras` of the intent of your launcher Activity. According to the data provided, you can handle the condition appropriately.

Set click_action in the notification payload

```java
{
  "notification": {
      "click_action": "activity action"
  },
 ....
}
```

In the mainfest you have to config the inter filter.

```java
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="some action" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

then when you click it, it will open that action activity:
If specified, an activity with a matching intent filter is launched when a user clicks on the notification.

You can set the click_action acton to match the browser chooser action, or "Intent.ACTION_VIEW" and data set like that `"https://"`